# Is it possible to restrict user ability to change runtime config parameter in PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, jwt

My quesion is about row level security and the [JWT Guide](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/jwt-guide/):

```
-- current role: superuser
set local jwt.claims.user_id to 2;
-- then define RLS using 'jwt.claims.user_id' setting for some tables
-- then switch to user
set local role user
-- now user can access those tables through the RLS policies.
```

1. How to prevent role user from changing *jwt.claims.user_id* setting?
2. Is it correct that user can not switch back to superuser after "set role"?

Comment: Why delete https://stackoverflow.com/q/53513936/6309? I would have loved to post an answer there.

Comment: Sorry, I've found the solution, that was gitolite installation error.

Comment: Yes, but the goal is to help others: you can add an answer to your own question